# RefreshNextPage with RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am using RxSwift to make a pull to refresh and refreshNextPage.

Currently, here is the viewModel I work so far:

```
public final class MomentViewModel {
// Property
let refreshTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()
let loadNextPageTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()
let loading = Variable<Bool>(false)
let posts = Variable<[Post]>([])
var pageIndex: Int = 0
let error = PublishSubject<Swift.Error>()
private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

public init() {

    let refreshRequest = loading.asObservable()
        .sample(refreshTrigger)
        .flatMap { loading -> Observable<Int> in
            if loading {
                return Observable.empty()
            } else {
                return Observable<Int>.create { observer in
                    self.pageIndex = 0
                    print("reset page index to 0")
                    observer.onNext(0)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                    return Disposables.create()
                }
            }
    }
    .debug("refreshRequest", trimOutput: false)

    let nextPageRequest = loading.asObservable()
        .sample(loadNextPageTrigger)
        .flatMap { loading -> Observable<Int> in
            if loading {
                return Observable.empty()
            } else {
                return Observable<Int>.create { [unowned self] observer in
                    self.pageIndex += 1
                    print(self.pageIndex)
                    observer.onNext(self.pageIndex)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                    return Disposables.create()
                }
            }
    }
    .debug("nextPageRequest", trimOutput: false)

    let request = Observable.merge(refreshRequest, nextPageRequest)
        .debug("Request", trimOutput: false)

    let response = request.flatMapLatest { page in
            RxAPIProvider.shared.getPostList(page: page).materialize()
        }
        .share(replay: 1)
        .elements()
        .debug("Response", trimOutput: false)

    Observable
        .combineLatest(request, response, posts.asObservable()) { request, response, posts in
            return self.pageIndex == 0 ? response : posts + response
        }
        .sample(response)
        .bind(to: posts)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    Observable
        .merge(request.map{ _ in true },
            response.map { _ in false },
            error.map { _ in false })
        .bind(to: loading)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

The `refreshTrigger` and `loadNextPageTrigger` is bind to difference target likes:

```
self.tableView.rx_reachedBottom
        .map { _ in () }
        .bind(to: self.viewModel.loadNextPageTrigger)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

self.refreshControl.rx.controlEvent(.valueChanged)
        .bind(to: self.viewModel.refreshTrigger)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)


self.rx.sentMessage(#selector(UIViewController.viewWillAppear(_:)))
        .map { _ in () }
        .bind(to: viewModel.refreshTrigger)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

**Question:**

When I scroll the tableView to bottom and trigger the `loadNextPageTrigger`, everything works fine.

However, if there is no more data in the next coming request, the loadnextPageTrigger will be triggered infinitely. 
Any help would be appreciated.

You can download the [Demo](https://github.com/wongzigii/RxPaginationDemo) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main idea is to check if all elements is loaded. I found in source code that you load parts by 20, so this condition should works fine `if loadedPosts < 20 then stop loading new part`. Here i share with you basic solution that you can refactor as you want (because i'm not good at `RxSwift`):

In `MomentViewModel` you should declare property

```
private var isAllLoaded = false
```

that set to true if you loaded all values. Then you should check every `[Post]` that came in response to set correct `isAllLoaded`:

```
Observable
    .combineLatest(request, response, posts.asObservable()) { request, response, posts in
        self.isAllLoaded = response.count < 20 // here the check
        return self.pageIndex == 0 ? response : posts + response
    }
    .sample(response)
    .bind(to: posts)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

And then in `nextPageRequest` in you should return `.empty()` observer if all parts have been loaded:

```
if loading {
    return Observable.empty()
} else {
    guard !self.isAllLoaded else { return Observable.empty() }

    return Observable<Int>.create { [unowned self] observer in
        self.pageIndex += 1
        print(self.pageIndex)
        observer.onNext(self.pageIndex)
        observer.onCompleted()
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

P.S. The [`MomentViewModel.swift`](https://pastebin.com/YsEqrQ1P) file to copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! @pacification. This works great, but I have no idea why requesting next page will skip the second page and pull the third page directly? Any idea?

Comment: @ZigiiWong, hi. i checked the problem, but i haven't same result as you. all request goes as they should: 0, 1, 2, 3...

Comment: I've finally solved this issue. Thanks for the help!!